# Does this type of distribution have a name?

Tags: probability, distributions, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, histogram

I have some integer data, produced by slightly convoluted numerical procedure, which is distributed between $0$ and $300$, with the most probable values being $0$ and $300$, and the least probable being $150$. Just by a bit of trial and error, I found that a function of the type $$p(x) \sim x^{-0.6} + (300 - x)^{-0.6}$$ (and normalised so it integrates to 1) seems to fit the data fairly well. So basically it seems like the sum of two power law distributions, where one starts high at zero and goes down for $x > 0$, and the other starts high at $300$ and goes down for $x < 300$.

[image]

**My question is:** Does this type of distribution have a name, and are there examples of applications or situations where this appears? Any references or additional info would be much appreciated.

**Background info:** The procedure that generated the data goes as follows:

- I have a counting variable, $n$, that is initially set to zero, and a height variable, $y$, that is also initially set to zero.
- For $i$ in $\{1, ..., 300\}$ I draw two random values: a binary variable $c_i$ which is 0 or 1 with equal probability, and a Rayleigh-distributed random variable, $r_i$.
- If $c_i=1$, I set $y_i = \max(y_{i-1}, r_i)$, consider the draw a success and increment $n$ by 1.
- If $r_i > y_{i-1}$, and $c_i=0$, then I set $y_i=0$, and consider the draw a failure and set $n$ to zero.
- If $r_i < y_{i-1}$, and $c_i=0$, I set $y_i=y_{i-1}$, and I also consider the draw a success, and increment $n$ by $1$.

The plot above shows the (rescaled) distribution of $n$, obtained from $100,000$ realizations.

**Update:** Based on the comments suggesting the beta distribution, I made the plot below. This seems to work well. The Wikipedia page for beta-binomial also mentions number of successes in Bernoulli trials with unknown probabilities, which seems relevant to my case.

**Update 2:**

For completeness, here is the code I used to generate $N$:

```py
def run_model(p=0.5):
    # Number of particles
    Np = 100000
    # Number of waves per timestep, assuming that dt >> Tp
    Nw = 300
    # Rayleigh distribution object
    r = rayleigh(scale=1)
    # Heights
    y = np.zeros(Np)
    # Array to count number of successive steps since last refloat
    N = np.zeros(Np)
    
    for i in range(Nw):
        # Draw Np random numbers
        zeta = r.rvs(Np)
        # zeta = np.random.uniform(size=Np) # Tried with other distributions as well
        # Draw binary number deciding if we increment or not
        flag = np.random.random(Np) < p
        # Increment or reset
        # For particles where flag is true, and zeta > y, increase y
        # The line below is the same as setting y = max(y_i-1, r_i) if flag == True
        y[flag & (zeta > y)] = zeta[flag & (zeta > y)]
        # For particles where flag is false, and zeta > y, reset y to zero
        mask = ~flag & (zeta > y)
        y[mask] = 0.0
        # Reset counter to zero for those particles that had y reset to 0
        # Increment counter for all others
        N = np.where(mask, 0, N+1)

    return y, N
```

[image]

The same with R

```
# Number of particles
Np = 100000
# Initial height
y = rep(0,Np)
# Number of trials
Nw = 500
# Probability of reset
p = 0.5
# Array to count number of successive steps since last reset
N = rep(0,Np)
    
for (i in 1:Nw) {
  # Draw Np random values
  ri = runif(Np)
  # Draw binary number yes/no
  flag = rbinom(Np,1,p)
  # For ri > y
  sel = (ri>y)
  y[sel == 1] = flag[sel == 1]*ri[sel == 1]
  # Increment counter 
  N = (N+1)*(1-sel*(1-flag))
}

hist(N/Nw, breaks = seq(0,1,0.01))
```

Comment: At a glance your histogram reminds me of either the [beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) or [beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) distributions depending on how attentive you wish to be to the integer support. But I'm not confident what a conventional term for your particular distribution would be.

Comment: related to Galen' comment and as side comment: you could also try a beta distribution on the normalised version, i.e. dividing alla observations by 300.

Comment: Beta or beta-binomial seems to be right. If any of you would care to put that in as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: The procedure is described in the question, where it says "Background info"

Comment: I see that I had several mistakes in my description, it was actually a bit more complicated. I have corrected the description (I think!), and for complete clarity I have added the python code I used to generate the results. Many thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: As far as anyone can tell, $(X/300)$ has a Beta$(0.6,0.6)$ distribution: this fits your data at least as well.  Modeling with a Beta distribution has some advantages, because this family is so well known, so well understood, and suggests some mechanisms and interpretations.  Regardless, if your objective goes beyond mere description of the data, you shouldn't be choosing distributions arbitrarily: use your understanding and theories of the data to suggest appropriate models.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Apparently I am a bit useless at writing both readable code and correct descriptions. I have edited the code for clarity (but I confirmed that the behaviour is identical to the previous version), and I have also corrected the description (at least I hope it's correct this time). In any case, the code is what I have actually used to generate the figure, so the code is by definition correct.

Comment: @whuber Although my ambition initially was simply to be able to draw random $n$ directly from some distribution rather than model them as above, I would indeed be very interested if anyone had a suggestion for why the beta distribution appears.

Comment: @Tor You seem to have a well-defined generative process. Echoing a tacit aspect of whuber's comment, you could mathematically formalize that process and derive the resulting distribution.

Comment: @Tor I have been able to reproduce your process. It seems like some sort of stick breaking process where the number of times that you break the stick is geometric distributed and the time to break the stick depends on the length of the stick which shortens every time. Then you repeat this untill you reach 300 steps and regard the last time that you renewed the stick.

Comment: @Galen Interesting thought, could you suggest some resources to read or places to start with this sort of approach? Personally I'm more of a pragmatical computational person than a very formal mathematical person, so I'm a bit out of my depth here (hence the question, in the first place).

Comment: @Tor Sextus Empiricus has made an interesting observation that I think it worth exploring. Generally having a collection of random variables $S$ and applying some function $f$ to them results in a new collection of random variables $W=f(S)$ with its own probability distribution. Working out the new distribution from the old distribution and the choice of function $f$ often involves a technique called "change in variables". In some cases it is very easy, in other cases it is very difficult, and often it is **too difficult**. I'm not sure about your case yet.

Comment: It is a mixture of two Beta distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution is a beta binomial distribution with parameters n=300 and $\alpha=\beta=0.5$.

---

For an approach to derive this, you can consider the distribution of the counting variable $x$ after $n$ draws. In the case of $p=0.5$ this looks for the first cases like

$$\begin{array}{cc|llll}
&&&&\rlap{x}\\
&&0&1&2&3&4\\\hline
&0&\frac{1}{1}\\
&1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\
n&2&\frac{3}{8}&\frac{2}{8}&\frac{3}{8}&\\
&3&\frac{5}{16}&\frac{3}{16}&\frac{3}{16}&\frac{5}{16}\\
&4&\frac{35}{128}&\frac{20}{128}&\frac{18}{128}&\frac{20}{128}&\frac{35}{128}\\
\end{array}$$

The values in each row can be related to the values in the row above. The probability of $x$ counts in draw $n$ is related to the probability of $x-1$ counts in draw $n-1$

$$P(x|n,p) = P(x-1|n-1,p) \cdot \left(1-\frac{p}{x} \right)$$

or

$$ \frac{P(x|n,p)}{P(x-1|n-1,p)} = \left(1-\frac{p}{x} \right) \tag{1}$$

This factor $1-p/x$ is related to the probability that the draw is a new maximum (the type of distribution that we draw from is irrelevant) and that the binomial variable is equal to one (in which case the count is reset to zero, and otherwise it increases by one).

The distribution that satisfies this relationship is the beta binomial distribution. With the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ then we have

$$ \begin{array}{}
\frac{P(x|n,\alpha,\beta)}{P(x-1|n-1,\alpha,\beta)} &=& \frac{
\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(n-x+1)} \frac{\Gamma(x+\alpha)\Gamma(n-x+\beta)}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+\beta)}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}}{\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(n-x+1)} \frac{\Gamma(x-1+\alpha)\Gamma(n-x+\beta)}{\Gamma(n-1+\alpha+\beta)}\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}} \\ 
&=&
\frac{
\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(x+1)} \frac{\Gamma(x+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+\alpha+\beta)}}{\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(x)} \frac{\Gamma(x-1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n-1+\alpha+\beta)}} \\
&=& \frac{n}{x}\frac{x+\alpha-1}{n+\alpha+\beta-1}
\end{array} \tag{2}$$

The equations (1) and (2) are equivalent when we choose $\alpha = 1-p$ and $\beta = p$.

---

Example demonstration with code:

[image: example when n = 50 and p = 0.33]

```
library(VGAM)

# Number of particles
Np = 10000
# Initial height
y = rep(0,Np)
# Number of trials
Nw = 50
# Probability of reset
p = 0.33
# Array to count number of successive steps since last reset
N = rep(0,Np)
    
for (i in 1:Nw) {
  # Draw Np random values
  ri = runif(Np)
  # Draw binary number yes/no
  flag = rbinom(Np,1,p)
  # For ri > y
  sel = (ri>y)
  y[sel == 1] = flag[sel == 1]*ri[sel == 1]
  # Increment counter 
  N = (N+1)*(1-sel*(1-flag))
}

h = hist(N, breaks = seq(-0.5,Nw+0.5,1), freq = 0)

### add a line for the beta binomial distribution 
k = 0:Nw
lines(k,dbetabinom.ab(k,Nw,p,1-p), lwd = 2, col = 2)
```

---

In a [previous version of this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/632264/7) I also considered a process with waiting times for a draw failure. With that approach one can also compute the probability,
but I could not use that approach to derive the relationship with the beta binomial distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll have a think about this. And if you edit your answer to include the mention of the beta distribution that you made in one of your comments above, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @Tor it looks like a beta distribution, but I am not sure it should be a beta distribution, or at least I don't understand intuitively why it should be a beta distribution.

Comment: True, but at least it seems for my purposes to be close enough to be practically indistinguishable from a beta distribution (or at least the beta-binomial distribution). It would be nice to have proof, but for the overall modelling I'm trying to do it seems plenty good enough.

Comment: @Tor I have updated the answer with a method to compute the exact distribution. It is using an itterative proces. Possibly there is a more direct function to describe the distribution.

Comment: @Tor What was your purpose that you only needed an approximate solution like a beta distribution? Couldn't you just use the obtained histogram for that same purpose? Also, where/how does this process occur, is there some practical application?

Comment: I am considering this as a (very simplified) model for how an object might interact with the shoreline in waves. Consider for example a piece of wood or buoyant plastics or whatever. Each time a wave hits, the object can either be pusher further up along the beach, or be washed back out to sea, with some probability. The Rayleigh distribution comes from the fact that wave heights are empirically found to be more or less Rayleigh-distributed. And the reason I would be happy to sample from an approximate distribution is just computational efficiency.

Comment: I might end up writing a paper about the overall model I'm working on, in which case your answer here would definitely be a useful thing to include. Please reach out if you are interested in being a co-author. You will find a link to my contact info in my profile.

Answer (score 4):

##### Natural Distributions

In terms of the typical visual form of this distribution, it looks to be closest to the uniquely named [U-shape distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-quadratic_distribution), which are distributions that have two extremes in occurrence but still have values in between these extremes:

[image]

Some examples of when this distribution occurs are outlined in [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2276773), which include:

- Class scores where several students score exceptionally well or exceptionally bad with every few people scoring points in between.
- The Galton Curve of Consumptivity, which basically showed that tuberculosis typically killed the very young or the very old.
- Percentages of deaf-mutes among children of parents.

##### Practical Ones

Having said all that, this distribution may not be the easiest to model from a practical perspective, particularly given that one cannot model it with properties that "flatten" the middle more. [A beta distribution](https://statisticsbyjim.com/probability/beta-distribution/) is probably more flexible in terms of getting the distribution to shape a certain way, as it can take on any number of visual forms (left-skewed, right-skewed, etc):

[image]

It likely gives you a closer fit to the data, so that would probably be more advisable in your case, which you seem to have already done.

Comment: The exponent in the U-quadratic is wrong, I think. The distribution of my data is flatter in the middle and steeper near the ends of the interval, if that makes sense. If you plot the U-quadratic on a semi-log scale, like I used in my plots above, you will see the difference immediately. The beta distribution has adjustable exponents and fits better.

Comment: Sorry for that. You were asking for distributions that look like this in the wild and examples of it. I already mentioned at the end of my answer that a beta distribution is likely a better fit, but I'll edit my answer to emphasize that point more.